# Calculate transfer time TCP flow

Tags: networking, tcp, sliding-window

There is a TCP flow between two hosts X and Y with a RTT of 100 ms and a bottleneck of 100 Mbps. How long will it take to transfer a 1 MB file from X to Y?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of too many other factors: maximum window size, IP channel characteristics, Nagles' algorithm on/off, client/server nodes answer times,  ...